# jQuery startInterval and clearInterval in different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am attempting to build a somewhat OOP jQuery plugin. Everything is going great, but I can't seem to get the start/pause function to implement correctly. I have the following 2 functions:

```
this.startAutoPlay = function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() { 
        obj.gotoNext(); 
    }, config.timing);
};

this.stopAutoPlay = function() {
    clearInterval(obj.startAutoPlay);
};
```

I just need a way to access the interval variable from within the `stopAutoPlay` function.

Any pointers?

Comment: Where did you saw jQuery stuff ?

Comment: *"jQuery startInterval and clearInterval in different functions"* `setInterval` and `clearInterval` are not jQuery functions.

Comment: It is a jQuery plugin that I'm writing. You can see the full code here https://github.com/iDev0urer/NUVISlider/blob/master/NUVISlider.js

Comment: @mascaliente, there is nothing related to jQuery in your post, it should not be tagged jquery (and oop btw).

Comment: @Hacketo: Well, if not with a tag, he should say he's using jQuery somewhere, in case it affects answers to the question. (It doesn't in this case, but if he doesn't know what's wrong, he can't know that when posting...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the interval that you set.

```
this.interval;
this.startAutoPlay = function() {
    obj.interval = setInterval(function() { 
        obj.gotoNext(); 
    }, config.timing);
};

this.stopAutoPlay = function() {
    clearInterval(obj.interval);
};
```

Comment: `this.interval;` is a no-op. You're right about the main problem, though.